# Replace exact word in SQL Server 2016, Replace function is working as "Like" but not exact

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an issue related to the `REPLACE` function. I have a string which contain words like `SOB40` and `SOB400`, want to replace with the exact string match with `SOB40` not `SOB400`.

I used the `REPLACE` function, but it is replacing both the words.

Below is the code snippet:

```
DECLARE @x varchar(max) = '[{"propertyName":"Test","propertyValue":"12345"}]',
        @y varchar(max) =
        '{{"sNumber":40,"name":"bush","description":"bush","suggested":["nnm"],"Names":["676"],"behaviors":["uy"],"documents":[],"propertyValues":[{ "propertyName": "OPs", "propertyValue": "08/26 13:22" },SOB40]},{"sNumber":400,"name":"as","description":"u","Names":["jll"],"documents":"5656","propertyValues":[{ "propertyName": "nn", "propertyValue": "01/05 12:59" },SOB400]}}'

SELECT
    @x = REPLACE(@y, ',SOB40', + SUBSTRING(@x, 2, LEN(@x) - 2))

SELECT @x
```

Output:

```
{{"sNumber":40,"name":"bush","description":"bush","suggested":["nnm"],"Names":["676"],"behaviors":["uy"],"documents":[],"propertyValues":[{ "propertyName": "OPs", "propertyValue": "08/26 13:22" }{"propertyName":"Test","propertyValue":"12345"}]},{"sNumber":400,"name":"as","description":"u","Names":["jll"],"documents":"5656","propertyValues":[{ "propertyName": "nn", "propertyValue": "01/05 12:59" }{"propertyName":"Test","propertyValue":"12345"}0]}}
```

If you observe `propertyValue":"12345"}**0**]}}` , here we are getting zero this is happening because of replace function.

Note: Tried Searching on internet, they are so many solutions, but none of them worked.

Also found solutions mentioning as `regx` replace, but when I copied the function to my SSMS, it says function not found.

Comment: T-SQL doesn't support Regex. If you did find solutions using Regex on the internet, they would have been CLR functions and I assume, therefore, you didn't add them to your instance before trying to use them.

Comment: The data *looks* like JSON, however, the value in your variable `@y` isn't valid JSON. If it *were* you could likely use the JSON support SQL Server contains to update the values as literals.

Comment: yeah, but we want to use it as a string, this is exsiting Sp so don't wan to change the logic now

Comment: JSON *is* just a string though.

Comment: Can you do this? REPLACE(@y,',SOB40]', + SUBSTRING(@x,2, LEN(@x)-2)) for character in end or REPLACE(@y,',SOB40,', + SUBSTRING(@x,2, LEN(@x)-2)) for character in other places. Basically just trying to figure out every possible combination to replace.

Comment: Try with adding `]` to both terms?